# 2 spinners with the same input cannot be the same -- error message required

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Trying to learn Java and make an app.
I have two spinners. They cannot have the same item (must be different). An error message appears when the button is clicked.

**Layout Concept:**

[image: layout concept]

I know this needs to be under my `button.setOnClickListener`:

```
theButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
if(spinner1.spinner() == spinner2.spinner){
                spinnerLabel.setError("Error");
            }
```

I know I am really butchering the logic and that is not correct. I would appreciate a push in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: By same item, do you mean same index or the Strings that the user chooses cannot be the same?

Comment: Same index. The spinners each have the same options to pick from. If there is a list of 5 colors, then spinner1 and spinner2 cannot both be blue. One can be blue but the other needs to be yellow.

Comment: I guess it could be a string array too (like strings.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that

1. Your spinner objects are called spinner1 and spinner2
2. Your button object is called theButton
3. Your TextView object is called errorTextView

Now, I think you should modify your onClick method like this:

```
theButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() == spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()){
            errorTextView.setError("Error");
        }
```

Try this out and let me know if you're stuck again.

Comment: Thank you Shashwat

Answer (score 0):

The Spinner class has a *getSelectedItem()* method.
Check if they're equal and implement your code.